# INNER JOIN + IN condition does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: Question and Quiz.

Quiz is a collection of Questions.

Quiz table looks like this:

### QuizdId  |  QuestionIds (NVARCHAR50)

```
  1    | 1,2,3,4,5
  2    | 6,7,8,9
```

The structure of Question table is not relevant. Its primary key is ID (integer)

For a given question Id, I want to select all the Question Data

This SQL does not work (gives syntax error)

```
SELECT qs.* FROM Questions AS qs
INNER JOIN Quiz AS qz on qs.ID IN (qz.QuestionIds)
WHERE qz.QuizId = 2;
```

SQL error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'qz.QuestionIds where qz.QuizId = 2

The below SQL does not give expected result. It gives only 1 question with ID 6. I guess the reason is that QuestionIds (in Quiz table) is nvarchar field and ID (in question table) is integer.

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE ID IN (SELECT QuestionIds FROM Quiz WHERE QuizId = 2)
```

What shall I do ?

I want to extract this via SQL / Procedures / Routines.

Comment: You should fix your design first, not the query...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - I realize that the DB design is not perfect. However, its too late now. I want to avoid DB redesign at this point.

Comment: Its too late to get the DB design right, we need to develop lots of hacks instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to join your two tables,

```
SELECT  qs.*
FROM    Questions qs
        INNER JOIN Quiz qz
            ON FIND_IN_SET(qs.ID, qz.QuestionIDs) > 0
WHERE   qz.QuizID = 2
```

but the way I could suggest is to normalize your table into 3-table design.

**Question Table**

- **QuestionID (PK)**
- QuestionText
- *other columns...*

**Quiz Table**

- **QuizID (PK)**
- *other columns...*

**Quiz_Question Table**

- QuestionID (FK) -- *Primary Key with QuizID*
- QuizID (FK)

..and if you were using the 3 table design, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT  qs.*
FROM    Questions qs
        INNER JOIN Quiz_Questions qq
            ON qq.QuestionID=qs.ID
WHERE   qq.QuizID = 2
```

Comment: indeed if you normalize the table you could indeed JOIN it and make it more database portable. function FIND_IN_SET is MySQL only..

Comment: @491243 Can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322156/update-in-procedure-does-not-work