# UPDATE in Procedure does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables: Question and Quiz.

Quiz is a collection of Questions.

Quiz table looks like this:

### QuizdId | QuestionIds (NVARCHAR50)

```
  1      |   1,2,3,4,5
  2      |   6,7,8,9
```

Question table has primary key ID (integer), Question and Status field

I want to write a procedure to update the status of all the questions in Question Table.

The following Query works in SQL Console

```
UPDATE questions SET ActiveStatus = 'X' 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT QuestionIds from quiz where QuizId = 2)) > 0
```

4 rows are updated here.

However, when I put the same query in a stored procedure and execute it with parameters, it does not work.

Stored Procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `update_quiz_status`(IN `QuizId` INT, IN `Status` VARCHAR(1))
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
UPDATE questions SET ActiveStatus = Status 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT QuestionIds from quiz where QuizId = QuizId)) > 0
```

Procedure has no syntax errors.

When I call the procedure from SQL console, I get the error:

```
call update_quiz_status(2,'X');
```

Error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I dont know why the query works in SQL console but not in stored procedure !

Is there any other way I can achieve this ? i.e. update the question status for a given quiz by SQL procedures.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql Stored Procedure's parameter with the same name as affecting's column, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715229/mysql-stored-procedures-parameter-with-the-same-name-as-affectings-column-is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

`SELECT QuestionIds from quiz where QuizId = QuizId`

In you mind the second `QuizId` refers to the passed paramenter. The parser, however, is seeing that as the `QuizId` in the `quiz` table and is therefore returning all rows from that table.

Change the name of your parameter and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a really, really bad data structure.  You should have a table `QuizQuestions` that has one row per question and quiz.

That said, the problem is this line:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT QuestionIds from quiz where QuizId = QuizId)) > 0
```

The `QuizId` is the same in both cases.  You should renamed the variable to something like `v_QuizId` and then use an alias for the `where` clause:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT QuestionIds from quiz q where q.QuizId = v_QuizId)) > 0
```